# Is there a way to meaningfully express $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}(x-1)^n}{n^k}$ for $k\neq 1$?

Tags: power-series

For the following series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{\left(n+1\right)}\left(x-1\right)^{n}}{n^{k}}$$
other than $k=1$, is there any way to express this series as a function for other values of $k$?

Answer (score 0):

Your series is related to the [polylogarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm):

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac {(-1)^{n+1}(x-1)^n}{n^k}=-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac {(1-x)^n}{n^k}=-\operatorname{Li}_k(1-x)$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! I've only studied high school math so I've never heard of the polylogarithm